# Error In Wifi Toggle Android Code

Tags: android, android-wifi

I get this error when I press the button for the wifi toggle and the app stops working.It mentions that the user has no permission to access wifi state.The thing is its already declared in the Manifest file.

> Permissions used:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

> Error

FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                              Process: com.example.something.callblocker, PID: 935
                                                                              java.lang.SecurityException: WifiService: Neither user 10052 nor current process has android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE.
                                                                                  at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1472)
                                                                                  at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1426)
                                                                                  at android.net.wifi.IWifiManager$Stub$Proxy.getWifiEnabledState(IWifiManager.java:808)
                                                                                  at android.net.wifi.WifiManager.getWifiState(WifiManager.java:1029)
                                                                                  at android.net.wifi.WifiManager.isWifiEnabled(WifiManager.java:1041)
                                                                                  at com.example.stamatis.callblocker.powersavings$2.onClick(powersavings.java:55)
                                                                                  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
                                                                                  at android.widget.CompoundButton.performClick(CompoundButton.java:100)
                                                                                  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
                                                                                  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Answer (score 0):

If this is happening and you are saying that android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE this is already present in manifest, then there is only one possibility that user has explicitly stopped this permission.

Check if this crash is in Marshmallow i.e API 23. Google has provided the user power to remove the permission of app explicitly.

You can read : http://www.greenbot.com/article/2990078/android/how-to-toggle-app-permissions-in-android-marshmallow.html

Only solution is to check for permission at runtime before doing toggle. 
This is how you can do this :

```
private boolean checkWriteExternalPermission()
{

    String permission = "android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE";
    int res = getContext().checkCallingOrSelfPermission(permission);
    return (res == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);            
}
```

Comment: I have a problem with getContext().It says method cannot be resolved.How do i fix this.(Sorry if the question is too stupid I am still a beginner)

Comment: I think I fixed the getContext by importing it(if that is correct) but now i have a problem with checkCallingOrSelfPermission and it says the same thing with getContext which is method cannot be resolved.

Comment: where are you using this code ? 
If in Activity then use this or ACTIVITY_NAME.this   . If in fragment you can use getActivity() instead of getContext()

Answer (score -1):

Needs to be looked at by authorities  for fraud and illegal activity steal the token page

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).